# Navigating a multi list using up/down arrow key using Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been trying to build a autocomplete using several "ul". Those list item should be navigable using up/down arrow key, but not sure what would be the best way to achieve that using Angular. I tried some work around with *ngFor, but that works for only one "ul" with "li". Here is the stackblitz with my code, but it has has some issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urnur5

```
//Code to handle navigation
navigateUsingKey(event) {
      switch (event.keyCode) {
          case 38: // this is the ascii of arrow up
                    this.linkIndex--;
                  break;
          case 40: // this is the ascii of arrow down
                    this.linkIndex++;
                  break;

      }
  }
```

Here is the html for the same.

```
<input (keyup)="navigateUsingKey($event)"/>
<div>
  <h4>Fruit</h4>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list1; let i = index;" [class.activeSearchLink]="i === linkIndex"> {{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>
  <h4>Vegie</h4>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list2; let i = index;" [class.activeSearchLink]="i === linkIndex"> {{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>
  <h4>Phone</h4>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list3; let i = index;" [class.activeSearchLink]="i === linkIndex"> {{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: so what you want instead here?

Comment: I want to navigate through list item sequentially using up/down arrow key.

Comment: means, first You want to start with `Fruit` section with item one `Apple`, and after next you want to visit `Vegie` section and then `Phone` section` and so on.. basically you want one section to traverse at a time. is it what you want?

Comment: Correct. That's what I want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working Demo** in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwfy7h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

you need to check section and length of each section.. so as you reached end or beginning of the section change section traversal at that time and change index according to that.

```
navigateUsingKey(event) {
  switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 38: // this is the ascii of arrow up        
        this.linkIndex === -1 ?  this.linkIndex = 0 : this.linkIndex-- ;
        // each section traversal...
        if(this.currentSectionIndex === 0){
          this.downTraverse(2,this.list3.length);
        } else if(this.currentSectionIndex === 2){
          this.downTraverse(1, this.list2.length);
        } else if(this.currentSectionIndex === 1){
          this.downTraverse(0, this.list1.length)
        }
      break;

      case 40: // this is the ascii of arrow down
        if(this.currentSectionIndex === 0){
          this.upTraverse(1, this.list1.length);
        } else if(this.currentSectionIndex === 1){
            this.upTraverse(2, this.list2.length);
        } else if(this.currentSectionIndex === 2){
            this.upTraverse(0, this.list3.length);
        }
        this.linkIndex++;
      break;       
  }
}

downTraverse(sectionIndex:number, listLength){
// calls when DOWN key press...
  this.linkIndex === -1 ? (this.currentSectionIndex = sectionIndex, this.linkIndex = listLength - 1) : '';
}
upTraverse(sectionIndex: number, listLength: number){
  // calls when UP key press...
  listLength-1 <= this.linkIndex ? (this.currentSectionIndex = sectionIndex, this.linkIndex = -1) : '';
}
```

**Template file is**

```
<input (keyup)="navigateUsingKey($event)"/>
<hr>
  <h5> You are in :   {{currentSectionIndex}} section
<hr>
<div>
  <h4 [ngClass]="{'section-color' : currentSectionIndex === 0}">Fruit </h4>
  <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let item of list1; let i = index;" [class.activeSearchLink]="i === linkIndex && currentSectionIndex === 0"> {{item.name}} 
     </li>
  </ul>
  <h4 [ngClass]="{'section-color' : currentSectionIndex === 1}">Vegie</h4>
  <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let item of list2; let i = index;" [class.activeSearchLink]="i === linkIndex && currentSectionIndex === 1"> {{item.name}}
    </li>
 </ul>
 <h4 [ngClass]="{'section-color' : currentSectionIndex === 2}">Phone</h4>
 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list3; let i = index;" [class.activeSearchLink]="i === linkIndex && currentSectionIndex === 2"> {{item.name}}
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you help me to focus the items inside list for the same ? I know you might be busy with lot's of stuff!, but it'll help me a lot. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwfy7h

Comment: FYI .. now on up/down key event we are trying to focus link one by one inside list ..not the list.

Comment: hello, check out this updated link... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwfy7h  is it okay?

Comment: I appreciate your help!. But, I want to highlight <a> one by one inside <li> now. Here is the example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwfy7h

Comment: your stackblitz link is not updated. if you want to edit it then you have to forke it first and then edit it and then share new link with me, then it can be saved new changes. Fork option is in top-nav bar of stackblitz

Comment: Here is the new stackblitz. Thanks so much for letting me know. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-62zfux

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212337/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-somedev).

Comment: hello, click on above commnet `continue this discussion in chat` and come to chat new window

Comment: Just curious if you could update this to be more dynamic with a for loop. Just not sure how that would work since the indexing is odd. In a real world scenario usually you would get a list of list from an endpoint.

Comment: @Andrew can you be more specific? Because there were ngFor of lists.

Comment: Well with only one ul>li>a with multiple list. So like a forEach (list of list) in this situation is basically what I'm asking, I've got it working with the code provided. However, it goes out of bounds if the currentSectionIndex is greater than 3 and the list size is only 2. List size changes depending on the query since that's sent back from the server.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Where can I find your email? I'd like to discuss this, thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242767/discussion-between-andrew-and-gaurangdhorda).